# stackoverflowのマークの意味です。タブレット端末で表示されません。マウスで合わせると、win10で表示されました。

Tags: サポート, ヘルプ

（参考）2 分間のツアーに参加する
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour

この質問は、趣旨が明確でわかりやすい・実用的である・建設的である
▲
0
▼
この質問は、調査や試行錯誤の跡がまったくない・内容が大変杜撰である
この質問をブックマーク。
□
この投稿のアクティビティを表示する。

Comment: こちらは何が主目的のご質問でしょうか？　たとえば、数字の上下にある三角マークの意味を教えて欲しいという質問なのか、それともタブレットで表示する方法を知りたいという質問なのか、いくつか考えられてよく分かりませんでした。[edit] していただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: 主目的は、ヘルプで見つける事ができないので、投稿しました。win10でわかりました。HUAWEIのandroidで、操作がわからなくてです。丁寧な回答、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

その辺は、ハードウェア(タブレット=タッチスクリーン対マウス)の違いとシステム/ソフトウェアの仕様策定/対応状況により発生する、仕方の無い現象と考えられます。

ブラウザのF12開発者ツールで見ると判りますが、それらの表示と消去は[`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event)/[`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event)イベントで処理されているようです。

タブレット等に付いているのは[`touch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Touch)インタフェースであり、名前が違うことと同じ機能のイベント(touchover/touchout)が存在しないことで分かる通り、これで上記イベントを発生させることは出来ないでしょう。
[Touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)

一応同等に扱うことが出来るように検討はされているようですが、まあ質問が出ているように完全では無いでしょう。
[TouchEvent と MouseEvent の両方をサポートする](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent)

> touch インターフェースは、タッチできるデバイス 上で高いユーザーエクスペリエンスを生み出すアプリケーションを可能にします。しかし、ウェブコンテンツの大部分がマウス入力でだけ操作できるように設計されている現実があります。したがって、ブラウザがタッチをサポートしていても、マウス入力のみを想定したコンテンツを直接修正することなく従来通り動作させるために、ブラウザはまだマウスイベントをエミュレートしなくてはなりません。
>
> 理想的には、タッチベースのアプリケーションは、明示的にマウスの入力に対処する必要はありません。しかし、ブラウザはマウスイベントをエミュレートしなければならないので、処理しなければならない相互問題がいくつかあります。以下は開発者のためのイベントの動作と予期しない問題についての詳細です。

またソフトウェアの仕様として同等の操作・表示が出来たとしても、タブレットでその位置に指等を持っていくということは、表示内容を少なからずそれらで覆うので見えない部分が発生しますし、そういうことが出来ない(非常に困難な)ハードウェアも存在しますので、なかなか互換に作ることは難しいでしょう。

---

なお装置のタイプによっては、上記処理そのものが登録されない場合もあるようです。

- キーボード(物理キー)+タッチパッド部分を取り外してタブレットにもなる2in1ノートPC
  →処理は登録されて、タッチパッドでマウスポインタを操作すると表示は行われる。
  　タッチスクリーンで操作すると表示は行われない。
- キーボード(タッチ式キー)+タッチパッド部分を360度回転させてタブレットになるノートPC
  →処理自体が登録されていない。
  　タッチパッドでマウスポインタを操作しても表示は行われない。
  　タッチスクリーンで操作しても表示は行われない。

---

ちなみにそれら **マークの意味** はこちらの記事の「投票」にかかわる内容になっています。
[投票が重要なのはなぜ？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

> 投票は、上質の質問と回答を提供するモデルの中心的なものです。投票によって以下が実現できます。
>
> - 良い内容がトップにあがる
> - 正しくない内容は下に降りる
> - 一貫して有益な内容を提供するユーザーには信用度が与えられ、サイトでより多くの権限が与えられる

[信用度とは何ですか？どうしたら上がりますか？また失うのはどんな時ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)
[権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)