# ヘルプセンター:「マイナス投票する」のヘルプを見易い/見付け易い位置に

Tags: 討議, サポート, ヘルプ

[マイナス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)の解説ページがありますが、[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help) ＞ [権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) の一覧表の名称や備考的な記述からのリンクとなっています。

しかしこれでは多くの人の目に触れていない(あるいは意識が変わってきている)のでは？ と思われます。
なぜなら、記述されている以下の内容に沿っているようには見えない(YouTubeの低評価程度の感覚では？と思われる)マイナス投票が時々行われている(その後のフォローも無い)ように感じられるので。

> **どんな時にマイナス投票したらいいですか?**
> はなはだしくずさんな、まったく努力していない投稿、または明らかに、そして危険なほど不正確な回答を見つけたら、マイナス票を使用してください。

> マイナス票は極端な場合のためにとっておいてください。コミュニケーションや編集の代わりを意図するものではありません。

それから、上記ページ記述と下記ページ記述では考え方に違いがあり、現状はこちらに近い(一部でもそう感じたらマイナス投票しやすい)と思われます。
[投票が重要なのはなぜ？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

> 反対票を投じることはその逆で、その投稿に間違った情報が含まれていること、調査が不十分であること、または情報を伝えていないことを示します。

[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)

> 「信用度」とは何ですか？
>
> サイトに無関係な質問や、正しくない回答を投稿するとマイナス票がつきます。

上記[マイナス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)の「マイナス票は極端な場合のためにとっておいてください。」を継続・推進したいなら、もう少しそのページにアクセスし易いようにリンクを貼るとか目立たせる工夫が必要でしょう。

一方、参加者の意識が変わってきているとして、それを追認するのなら、それに合わせた記述や信用度の取り扱いに関するシステムの見直しが必要でしょう。

---

継続・推進案の例

上記も含めて以下4つくらいを[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)ページの **権限** カテゴリの下にリンクを貼る。

- [プラス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)
- [どこでもコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)
- [マイナス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)
- [質問と回答の編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

下の図の赤く囲った部分ですね。
[image: 権限カテゴリ]

あるいはその上の抜粋記述のどこか(以下2つくらい)にするのも良いかもしれません。
[image: マイナス投票]

[image: 信用度]

---

**↑↑ ここまでが ヘルプを見やすい位置に について**

**↓↓ これ以後は その他の話 と コメントへの応答です**

---

見直し案の例

マイナス評価を重大に捉えない、単なる複数回答間の賛成・反対や順位投票と考え、そのようにシステムを変更する。
マイナス投票する人・された人の信用度を変えない。

へルプの記述も、それに合わせて変更する。

信用度のマイナスはこちらの通報結果に担当させる。
(それから1回で大幅にマイナスするのは止めるか、通報内容で差を付けた方が良いでしょう)
[誰かが何か悪いことをしているのを見つけたら？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)

---

ついでに：

[マイナス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)の最後の部分ですが、以下のように追加して欲しいところですね。
太字が追加部分。(太字化は実際の記事には不要)

> マイナス投票の代わりに
>
> - **対象が回答の場合は、あなたが正しいorより良い回答を投稿してください。**
> - 投稿がスパムや不快である場合は、通報します。
> - 質問が重複またはトピックから外れている場合は、通報してモデレーターの注意を喚起します。
> - 何かが間違っている場合はコメントを残すか投稿を編集して訂正してください。

---

**コメントが多くなると省略されるのを避けて以下に移動**

「信用度が上がって...サジェストされるはず」のコメントに対して：

何か通知はあったと思います。ただパッとアクセス出来る所に書いてある内容と、主題として書いてあるとも言うべき所の内容にズレがあって、システム的には存在が判り難い所に書いてある仕様で作られているというのがイマイチよろしくないと思われます。例えばこの古い記事[質問に対して、反対票を入れる評価基準はありますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1876/26370)の当時にはそのヘルプが無かったような議論の展開ですが、「評価基準」が明確で統一されていてシステムもその通り動作している、というのは重要でしょう。

---

「マイナス投票できるようになったときに...」のコメントに対して：

ツールチップによる表示では、ヒントにはなってもヘルプ記事の内容は伝わらないでしょう。

最近もMetaで[stackoverflowのマークの意味です。タブレット端末で表示されません。マウスで合わせると、win10で表示されました。](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3363/26370)の記事があって、コメントに「主目的は、ヘルプで見つける事ができないので、投稿しました。」と付いていました。能動的に探そうと思っても見つからないのでは無いのと一緒では？

質問や私が調べたようにスマホ・タブレット系端末ではツールチップ表示されない可能性も高いですし。

---

「既存の回答を改善するだけで良い場合はそのように行動すれば良いからです。」のコメントに対して：

実態としてそのように行動してくれる人が少ないからですね。

多くの人は単にマイナス投票してくれます。
コメントだけしてくれる人はそれなりに居ますが、マイナス投票と同時のように(偶然？)見える人もチラホラ見受けられます。

その前のコメントの「割と充分目立っているけど無視されていたり何かしら個々人の理由があって使われていたりするのでは」と併せて、上記「...評価基準は...」の最後の回答、

> [マイナス票しか入れない人にコメントを求めたところで建設的な意見が得られるかどうかは微妙です。](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1891/26370)

のような行動を抑止(一瞬ためらう程度？)して建設的な意見・行動を引き出せれば良いと思っています。

投票システムそのものが複数回答はあって当然と考えられるし、マイナス投票を決断できるほどの知識・経験があるなら、それを回答にしてもらった方が早くて、その回答にプラス投票が付いて評価されていくのがStackOverflowのモデル的に正しいと思うからです。

ただ、マイナス投票できるシステムそのものが回答自体を抑止している面もあるので、モデル的な理想と運用の実態が合わないジレンマを抱えているでしょう。
[コメントで回答する理由を教えてください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3242/26370)

Comment: 一応、信用度が上がってマイナス投票できるようになったときに記事がサジェストされるはず……ではあります。

Comment: マイナス投票できるようになったときにマイナス投票とは何なのかが通知によって分かるようになっていれば、新規の方が概念を知るのには充分と思います。ヘルプセンターは誰もが何度も確認するような場所ではないので、もしなされるべきでないマイナス投票がよくあるのであれば、それはヘルプを目立たせることではなくメタでの議論や通報などのモデレーションによってなされるべきかもな、と考えました。今以上に目立たせてどのくらい意味があるのだろうと思っていて、たとえば今でもマイナス投票しようとするとツールチップに「この質問は（中略）内容がたいへん杜撰である」などと出るため、割と充分目立っているけど無視されていたり何かしら個々人の理由があって使われていたりするのでは、という気がしています。

Comment: 「対象が回答の場合は、あなたが正しいorより良い回答を投稿してください。」と追記するのは強めに反対です。既存の回答を改善するだけで良い場合はそのように行動すれば良いからです。

Comment: 「ヘルプを見やすい位置に」と「その他の話」は分けて議論すべきかと思います。

Comment: 「分けて議論」は段落ではなく、投稿を分けたほうがいいのでは？という提案でした。